# websocket socket.io dir nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a question regarding socket.io and dir

I have an api to validate login / jwt and etc

I'm starting to create a websocket server to create a joken po game,
one question i already have this api folder, should i create my websocket server inside this src? Or is it better to create another folder for this separate websocket server and it will consume my login api and others dates

and about having to pass html directory on nodejs to use socketio ex:

```
webApp.get ('/', (req, res, next) => {
res.sendFile (__ dirname + 'game.html'
});
```

How would I do if I create in a separate folder from my front end how would I be able to communicate?
ex: my front end in front end folder
my back end in backend folder

Comment: This question is very confusing and broad. There is no reason you cannot use the same server for your socket.io server and your existing API endpoints.

Comment: Oh nice, yes I don't speak english very well.
What about passing the directory on routes etc etc

my html files are in another folder

example i have a folder with my backend (api + server wbsckt) and my front end reactjs in different directories, my main question is this set up socket.io for different directories+

Comment: Are you express for your current server?

Comment: yess i use express.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58864595/62282)

Comment: I understand it was very similar to what I do with my common routes, but I was still unsure how to access them through my front end in react

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58923582/62282)

Comment: @SamuelG omg 
u are the man

Comment: Samuel just ask me one more question? regarding the first question you sent me,                           you said this: I would rather create endpoints in files - same as you do for express routes, and init these in your server.js as follows.... 
In case I can create multiple endpoints?

Comment: example: io.on('connection', socket => {
   require('./myendpointexample2')(socket);
}); io.on('connection', socket => {
   require('./myendpointexample3')(socket);
});

Comment: Samuel make an answer for me to vote positive for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your existing express server to host your socket.io instance. You can reuse all the same infrastructure in place and continue to use jwt tokens for your authentication with socket.io. Look at the [socketio-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-jwt) package on npm.

```
const socketioJwt = require('socketio-jwt');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// rest of your express config
...

const server = app.listen(PORT,
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`)
);

const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.use(socketioJwt.authorize({
  secret: 'your secret or public key',
  handshake: true
}));

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('hello!', socket.decoded_token.name);

  socket.emit('hello', {message: 'hello world'});

  socket.on('myevent', myhandler);
});
```

Ideally, you can simply use socket.io for all your backend communication.

In react you would simply import the [socket.io client](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/) and then connect as follows:

```
let socket = null;

function App() {

  useEffect(() => {

    async function connect () {
       socket = io.connect('http://myserver');
    }
    connect();

  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
       Hello
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

There is a lot to cover and it is a broad question, but you have some starting points now to continue your research.

Comment: thanks a lot bro, about socket.jwt 
could you ask me a question?
I already have a jwt auth and verify in my api, could I use it to validate the route? Or would I have to use socket.jwt to do its token generation and validatio

Comment: I got a little confused with jwt, kk
I already use jwt in my login route / so could I use my old jwt validation to validate the socket? Or in case it would have to have two jwt?

Why wouldn't it make much sense to have these two authentications, in which case as you said it is a good option to use websocket for all communications?
login / get user / etc etc?

Comment: In other words, would my api become unnecessary?
Would have to redesign routes to use with websocket

Comment: It depends on your client needs. If you only need to access the backend every so often, then it will use fewer server resources to simply use http as needed. If you need realtime or very chatty connections, then socket.io is a better choice and you can reuse the majority of your existing express code.

Comment: thanks bro, as i'm just doing for study i don't think it is necessary so i could use my old jwt method to request validation for socket.io or would it have to do with socket.jwt?

Comment: If you doing it for study, then simply do the exercise with both. JWT auth is really essential to know and many developers battle with it. It is worth looking at [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/) too which is pretty widely used.

Comment: ty bro i will try to auth jwt with my websocket server, i already use passport for my routes from my api

Comment: In case I could use passport to jwt my websocket server? using id socket as payload?